# Obtaining current GCC architecture

Tags: gcc

How can I find out what the `-march` default argument is for the current architecture if I don't supply any?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

`gcc -dumpmachine` gives you the target triplet, e.g. `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`

If `gcc -v` shows GCC was configured with a `--with-arch` option (or `--with-arch-32` and/or `--with-arch-64`) then that's what will be the default.

Without a `--with-arch` option (and if there isn't a custom specs file in use) then the arch used will be the default for the target.

For x86, up to and including GCC 4.4, the default for 32-bit was `-march=i386` and for 64-bit was `-march=x86-64` (note the hyphen instead of underscore.)

For x86 with GCC 4.5 and later versions the default arch is inferred from the target triplet i.e. configuring for `i586-pc-linux-gnu` means the default is `-march=i586`, configuring for `core2-pc-linux-gnu` means the default is `-march=core2`.

Some other platforms also infer the default arch from the target triplet (and have done since before GCC 4.4) so e.g. `ultrasparc2-sun-solaris2.10` implies `-march=ultrasparc2`.

Comment: The `gcc -dumpmachine` options is perfect.  Another example of how a two second search on stackoverflow avoids another read of the gcc man page!

Comment: I have read the manual, and enjoyed it.  What I meant was that you can search stackoverflow with more human search terms rather than going through the man page.  For example, I have used `gcc -dumpmachine` before but couldn't remember the argument name.  However I can't do a easy search in the man page for the correct argument sometimes.  Maybe I should change "avoids another read of" to "avoids another search through" ;)

Comment: Ah yes, fair enough, that's certainly easier than remembering the exact term to search for in the manual, because if you could remember it you wouldn't need to look it up!

Comment: The only problem is that MinGW says just `mingw32` and I don't see any option to find whether it means i386 or i486 or i686 or what (unlike cygwin gcc for mingw, which says i686-pc-mingw).

Comment: The specs file can also modify what particular tuning flags are used. So beware of that. Effectively the trick with `echo | gcc -v -E - 2>&1 | grep cc1` shown in another answer will reveal what the specs file is using.

Comment: Doesn't the `gcc -dumpmachine` just give you the target by which your gcc was built for?  I'm not sure it gives you the exact architecture of your machine.

Comment: @annoying_squid I never claimed it tells you that. It tells you the target GCC as built for, which can determine the default `-march` value, which is what the question is about. The question is not about the exact architecture of the machine, it's about the default settings for a particular build of GCC, which depends on the target GCC was built for, and other configure options ... as the answer explains.

Comment: fyi there is also `gcc -dumpversion`

Answer (score 19):

I found this gem on the [GCC mailing list](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2011-11/msg00250.html) that prints the default `-march` and `mtune` parameters:

```
$ echo | gcc -v -E - 2>&1 | grep cc1
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.0/cc1 -E -quiet -v - -mtune=generic -march=x86-64
```

Basically, you are compiling an empty file from stdin and while doing so, you print the commands.

Comment: Makes sense to point out that `-m32` and `-m64` can be used on the `gcc` invocation to ask for either 32-bit or 64-bit (default) targets.

Answer (score 15):

You can use `gcc -Q --help=<type>` to list the current option values of the given `<type>`.  Thus:

```
$ gcc -Q --help=target | grep march
  -march=                           x86-64
$ gcc -m32 -Q --help=target | grep march
  -march=                           i686
$ i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -Q --help=target | grep march
  -march=                           pentiumpro
```

Edit: Actually, this option is not as generally useful as it appears, because target-specific defaults [are not reflected in the output](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=39851).

Comment: This is very helpful for GCC 6 and later, where it does print target-specific defaults.

Answer (score 6):

Running the command

```
gcc -v
```

will show something like this:

```
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Configured with: /build/src/gcc-4.7.1/configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=https://bugs.archlinux.org/ --enable-languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,go,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-clocale=gnu --disable-libstdcxx-pch --enable-libstdcxx-time --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-ppl --enable-cloog-backend=isl --disable-ppl-version-check --disable-cloog-version-check --enable-lto --enable-gold --enable-ld=default --enable-plugin --with-plugin-ld=ld.gold --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-multilib --disable-libssp --disable-build-with-cxx --disable-build-poststage1-with-cxx --enable-checking=release
Thread model: posix
gcc versie 4.7.1 (GCC)
```

The `Target:` line is what you want. You should be able to deduce enough information from this.

Comment: What part of "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu" can you use with `-march`?

Comment: The first part: `x86_64`. But that is a general one. A full list can be found int the GCC manual: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.1.0/gcc/x86-Options.html#x86-Options.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the answer is there isn't any equivalent. Either you don't specify `-march=` and the compiler uses the architecture's minimal instruction set, or you do specify `-march=` and it uses features of whichever cpu model you ask for. So there is no way to write a `-march=` option that is equivalent to omitting the `-march` option.

Maybe if you explain what motivated the question we could improve on this answer.