# Why I can't define __int128_t?

Tags: c++

My compiler is GNU GCC. What I have to do to work on __int128_t? Do I have to include some library or change compiler?

Comment: GCC supports `__int128` on a 64-bit architecture.  Are you on a 64-bit architecture?

Comment: @Eljay I have 64-bit Windows.

Comment: Have you tried GCC's `__int128`?

Comment: @Eljay yes, it also doesn't work.

Comment: I'd check to make sure you are running a GCC that targets 64-bit architecture.  You may be producing 32-bit executables.

Comment: @Eljay how to check it? It is about right version of GCC?

Comment: `std::cout << (sizeof(void*) * 8) << "\n";` should be a good indicator.

Comment: Alternatively, `touch /tmp/empty.cpp` and then `g++ -E -dM /tmp/empty.cpp | grep -i -e amd -e x86`

Comment: I have the newest gcc:  https://jmeubank.github.io/tdm-gcc/. But __int128 still doesn't work.

Comment: @Eljay what it means to be on 64-bit architecture?

Comment: `touch empty.cpp` then `g++ -E -dM empty.cpp` and look for `#define _LP64 1` or something like that, or other defines with the word `WIDTH` in them.

Comment: `g++ -v` or `g++ -dumpmachine` should also be able to tell you which architecture you're on.  More info at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11727855/obtaining-current-gcc-architecture

Comment: @Eljay I have x86_64-linux-gnu.

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html), I can only surmise that your *particular* 64-bit platform does not have an integer mode wide enough to hold 128 bits, which is why there is no `__int128`.